# WordPress menu error on top of page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have an error with the menus on WordPress site fabzar.com it show correct on front page but when you click one of the products the menu changes and picks up the page name

Do you know what causes this and how to fix it

Thanks in advance

Heres the header Code.
    
     >

```
<title>
<?php

    wp_title( ' ', true );

?>
</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>

<?php

    wp_head();

?>  

<?php do_action('PricerrTheme_before_head_tag_open'); ?>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/my-script.js"></script>
 <!-- ########################################### -->

         <script type="text/javascript">
function suggest(inputString){

    if(inputString.length == 0) {
        $('#suggestions').fadeOut();
    } else {
    $('#big-search').addClass('load');
        $.post("<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=autosuggest_it", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data){
            if(data.length >0) {

                    var stringa = data.charAt(data.length-1);
                            if(stringa == '0') data = data.slice(0, -1);
                            else data = data.slice(0, -2);



                $('#suggestions').fadeIn();
                $('#suggestionsList').html(data);
                $('#big-search').removeClass('load');
            }
        });
    }
}

function fill(thisValue) {
    $('#big-search').val(thisValue);
    setTimeout("$('#suggestions').fadeOut();", 600);
}


$(document).ready(function(){

$(".expnd_col").click(function() { 

    var rels = $(this).attr('rel');
    $("#term_submenu" + rels).toggle();
    return false;


});

</script>
 <?php

    $PricerrTheme_color_for_footer = get_option('PricerrTheme_color_for_footer');
    if(!empty($PricerrTheme_color_for_footer))
    {
        echo '<style> #footer { background:#'.$PricerrTheme_color_for_footer.' }</style>';  
    }


    $PricerrTheme_color_for_bk = get_option('PricerrTheme_color_for_bk');
    if(!empty($PricerrTheme_color_for_bk))
    {
        echo '<style> body { background:#'.$PricerrTheme_color_for_bk.' }</style>'; 
    }

    $PricerrTheme_color_for_top_links = get_option('PricerrTheme_color_for_top_links');
    if(!empty($PricerrTheme_color_for_top_links))
    {
        echo '<style> .top-links { background:#'.$PricerrTheme_color_for_top_links.' }</style>';    
    }


    //----------------------

    $PricerrTheme_home_page_layout = get_option('PricerrTheme_home_page_layout');
    if(PricerrTheme_is_home()):
        if($PricerrTheme_home_page_layout == "4"):
            echo '<style>#content { float:right } #right-sidebar { float:left; }</style>';
        endif;

        if($PricerrTheme_home_page_layout == "5"):
            echo '<style>#content { width:100%; } .main-how-it-works{ width:100% }</style>';
        endif;

        if($PricerrTheme_home_page_layout == "3"):
            echo '<style>#content { width:520px } .title_holder { width:385px; } #left-sidebar{ margin-right:15px;}
            .main-how-it-works { width:520px; } .i_will_mainbox{ width:240px } .how-does-it-work-btn { top:30% }</style>';
        endif;


        if($PricerrTheme_home_page_layout == "2"):
            echo '<style>#content { width:520px } #left-sidebar{ float:right } #left-sidebar{ margin-right:15px; } .title_holder { width:385px; }
            .main-how-it-works { width:520px; } .i_will_mainbox{ width:240px } .how-does-it-work-btn { top:30% }</style>';
        endif;

    endif;


 ?>

 <!-- ########################################## -->

</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?> >
<div id="my_container">

 <div class="main_links">
    <div class="top-links">

                        <?php 
                            if(is_user_logged_in())
                            {
                                global $current_user;
                                get_currentuserinfo();
                                echo '<a href="'.PricerrTheme_my_account_link().'">';
                                echo sprintf(__('Welcome, %s', 'PricerrTheme'), $current_user->user_login );
                                echo '</a>';


                            }

                            if(current_user_can('manage_options')) {?> <a href="<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>/wp-admin"><?php echo __("Wp-Admin"); ?></a> <?php }

                        ?>

                        <a href="<?php bloginfo('siteurl') ?>"><?php echo __("Home","PricerrTheme"); ?></a> 
                        <a href="<?php echo PricerrTheme_post_new_link(); ?>"><?php echo __("Post New","PricerrTheme"); ?></a> 
                        <?php if(get_option('PricerrTheme_enable_blog') != "no") { ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo PricerrTheme_blog_link(); ?>"><?php echo __("Blog","PricerrTheme"); ?></a> 
                        <?php } ?>



                <?php

                        $menu_name = 'Pricerr_top_menu_header';

                        if ( ( $locations = get_nav_menu_locations() ) && isset( $locations[ $menu_name ] ) ) {
                        $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $menu_name ] );

                        $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);


                        foreach ( (array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item ) {
                            $title = $menu_item->title;
                            $url = $menu_item->url;
                            if(!empty($title))
                            echo '<a href="' . $url . '">' . $title . '</a> ';
                        }

                        }


                        ?>



                        <?php

                            if(is_user_logged_in())
                            {
                                $uid = $current_user->ID;
                                $pricerrTheme_get_unread_number_messages = pricerrTheme_get_unread_number_messages($uid);

                                if($pricerrTheme_get_unread_number_messages > 0) $sk = '  <span class="the_one_mess">'.$pricerrTheme_get_unread_number_messages.'</span>';
                                else $sk = '';

                                ?>

                                <a href="<?php echo PricerrTheme_my_account_link(); ?>"><?php echo sprintf(__("MyAccount %s","PricerrTheme"), $sk); ?></a>
                        <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(); ?>"><?php echo __("Log Out","PricerrTheme"); ?></a>

                                <?php
                            }
                            else
                                {


                        ?>

                        <a href="<?php bloginfo('siteurl') ?>/wp-login.php?action=register"><?php echo __("Register","PricerrTheme"); ?></a>
                        <a href="<?php bloginfo('siteurl') ?>/wp-login.php"><?php echo __("Log In","PricerrTheme"); ?></a>
                        <?php } ?>



                        <a href="<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>/?feed=rss2&amp;post_type=job"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/rss_icon.png" 
                border="0" width="19" height="19" alt="rss icon" /></a>


                    </div>
    </div>

    <div id="header">   


        <div class="middle-header-bg">
            <div class="middle-header" id="middle-header-id">

                    <?php
                        $logo = get_option('PricerrTheme_logo_url');
                        if(empty($logo)) $logo = get_bloginfo('template_url').'/images/logo.png';
                    ?>
                    <a href="<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>"><img id="logo" src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" /></a>


            <!-- ######### -->


            <div class="search_box_main">
       <?php

    global $wp_query;
    $query_vars = $wp_query->query_vars;

    $job_category   = $query_vars['job_category'];
    if(empty($job_category))    $job_category = "all";  

    $job_sort       = $query_vars['job_sort'];
    $job_tax        = $query_vars['job_tax'];

//----------        

    if(empty($job_category))    $job_category   = "all";
    if(empty($page))            $page           = "1";
    if(empty($job_sort))        $job_sort       = "auto";
    if(empty($job_tax))         $job_tax        = "category";


    $term_search    = $query_vars['term_search']; 
    global $default_search;

       ?>

    <div id="suggest" >
                <form method="get" action="<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>"> <input type="hidden" value="1" name="search_me_now" />

                    <div class="search_left">
                    <input type="text" onfocus="this.value=''" id="big-search" name="term" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="suggest(this.value);"   value="<?php if(!empty($term_search)) echo htmlspecialchars($term_search); 
                    else echo $default_search; ?>" /></div>

                <div class="search_left">           
                <input type="image" width="29" id="big-search-submit" name="search_me" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/search_icon.png" /></div>
                </form>

                <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" style="z-index:999;display: none;"> <img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/arrow.png" style="position: relative; top: -12px; left: 30px;" alt="upArrow" />
    <div class="suggestionList" id="suggestionsList"> &nbsp; </div>
  </div></div>


            <!-- #############################-->
            </div>
             <?php uberMenu_easyIntegrate(); ?> 
        </div> <!-- middle-header-bg -->



    </div>  </div>  



    <div id="main">
```

Heres the page code were it happens to

Comment: You may need to be more specific about the problem in order to receive useful feedback.  It's also good if you can provide some code and/or screenshots, rather than just asking people to look at your site.

Comment: There's error in your template's code. So if you can share the code to specific pages, its possible to help out. Otherwise its a guess game for others.